# Change y axis display when difference in data is very small

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I had many datasets in processing, however, I noticed some of figures are like this following figure, the true value is 3.85303 but in the y axis it displays as 0.000003 to 0.00010, how do I replace current y axis to 3.853033 to 3.853040 automatically (I have many datasets to auto-processing)?

[image]

```
plot = matplotlib.pyplot
plot.plot(x_data, y, marker='o',markersize=3, label = name)
plot.xlabel('Date', fontsize=10)
plot.ylabel('Cost($)', fontsize=16)
plot.xticks(fontsize=10, rotation=90)
plot.legend(loc='upper right')
```

I tried plot.ylim but it appears not to be automatic processing that I want.

Thank you!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Axes should autoscale by default, do you have some sample code to share?

Comment: Hi TomNash, it is autoscaled, the problem is that few figures showing a format that I do not want, you can check my image link to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can modify the format of y axis by using a construct similar to below:

ytickformat('%.xf') where x is the number of places after decimal.

Since you are showing $ value on Y axis - here is some additional info on the formatting.

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ytickformat.html